# Mongoose seems to fail quietly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise

So have a completely separate issue (I think) which is saving an array to a mongo document. So I took out that part, created a data structure that would have the same issue to try to resolve it. But now my test code seems to finish before the save function returns, just not certain how to resolve either issue, or if they potentially are connected.

The mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var offerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    closeDate: Date,
    settleDate: Date,
    schemaVersion: Number,
    _offered: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}], //Ids of thos offered
    _offerDate: { type: Date },// The date they where offered
    _accepted: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],//Ids of those accepted
    _acceptedDate: [{ type: Date }], //Dates when accepted
});



// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('offer', offerSchema);
```

So I have written the code below to recreate the issue, the below code should work but not store a value in _offered.

```
var offer = require('../models/offerSchema.js')
var indata = {"offer":{"closeDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z","settleDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z","type":1,"_offered":[{"id":"55dc7994ed0fcf4a58d4a689"},{"id":"55dcd30915e3be545a51bebd"}],"_offerDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z"}}

var thisOffer = indata.offer
for ( var i in thisOffer ){
    console.log("Got "+ i +" is " + thisOffer[i])

}
var myOffer = new offer(thisOffer);
myOffer._offered = undefined
var promise =
myOffer.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Got an error: ' + err)
    }
    console.log('Got an id: ' + myOffer._id)
    return 0;
}).then(function() {
    console.log("I get here and quit?");
})
```

However, the code seems to complete before the save have completed, and I am actually not certain how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing logic with callbacks and promises. So you do not need the callback, just act on the promise returned:

```js
myOffer._offered = undefined
myOffer.save()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("I get here and quit?");
  })
  .then(null,function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

I noticed you made another attempt using Bluebird promises, but it is not necessary as if you implement as shown here any errors will be appropriately routed.

Threre are notes that mongooose 5.x is slated to have a more standardised approach to promises and/or directly use Bluebird promises when configured

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the issue. mongoose save is not promisified (or at least that is what I recon the issue is), changed the first part to use bluebird for promises, then changed the save to use saveAsync as below
Schema (and connection, and bluebird)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://webbetcha:M0t0rWrl3d@localhost/betchadb');
ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var offerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    closeDate: Date,
    settleDate: Date,
    schemaVersion: Number,
    _offered: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}], //Ids of thos offered
    _offerDate: { type: Date },// The date they where offered
    _accepted: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],//Ids of those accepted
    _acceptedDate: [{ type: Date }], //Dates when accepted
});



// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('offer', offerSchema);
```

And the code

```
var offer = require('../models/offerSchema.js');

var indata = {"offer":{"closeDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z","settleDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z","type":1,"_offered":[{"id":"55dc7994ed0fcf4a58d4a689"},{"id":"55dcd30915e3be545a51bebd"}],"_offerDate":"2015-08-31T13:26:36.512Z"}}

var thisOffer = indata.offer
for ( var i in thisOffer ){
    console.log("Got "+ i +" is " + thisOffer[i])

}
var myOffer = new offer(thisOffer);
myOffer._offered = undefined
myOffer.saveAsync()
.then(function(doc){
        console.log('Got an id: ' + myOffer._id)
    })
.catch(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Got an error: ' + err)
    }
});
```